# Impact of using UUIDs with an UNIQUE index vs. as a PK?

Tags: mysql

It's well known how the performance of random UUIDs as PKs degrades terribly as the table increases in size. Would an UNIQUE index for a non-PK UUID column have the same impact?

Comment: Interesting question, and absent any science whatsoever, I would guess it probably does degrade similarly.  This might be better asked over at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I considered that. I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: You will find this interesting: http://iops.io/blog/storing-billions-uuid-fields-mysql-innodb/

Comment: @kums I already figured out storing as binary(16) is the best option, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I figured out that the impact is much more significant with PKs since they are used as the clustered index by default, therefore determining how the table itself is clustered. A non-PK unique index with random values definitely has more impact than the same index with sequential values, but it doesn't change how the table is clustered.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the only differences between a `PRIMARY KEY` index and a `UNIQUE` index are:

- `PRIMARY KEY` implies `NOT NULL`
- InnoDB physically orders rows on disk according to the `PRIMARY KEY` column(s)

But assuming that

- `UUID` will be defined as `NOT NULL` anyways
- one never needs to query a range of (consecutive) UUID's

... there should be no practical difference.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. The PRIMARY KEY is the clustered index.